# URLImages in list renderer disappearing on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I have a custom list renderer that has a logo for a business in it.  It has a label Logo_URLImage that has the placeholder image.  In my code I get the data and assign HashMaps to the list model, h.put("Logo_URLImage",imageURL);  where imageURL is a string that has the absolute URL to the image.

On Android it seems to always work, but most of the testing has been on iOS devices.  What happens is that images are updated as you'd expect the first time or two that you run it.  A run later on will show blank images (flash the place holder image and then blank) and once that happens images will never come back.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet of how you used the imageURL?

Comment: Are you calling similar imageURL more than once URLImage?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you defined the `LogoName` map entry. Check that it is unique per image?

Check that it doesn't include special characters that might cause an issue.